# Travis error: package is not in the npm registry

Tags: npm, travis-ci

I've built an npm package which is private. Travis then builds my app and throw an error `@<organization>/<package-name> is not in the npm registry`.

I've created a new NPM_TOKEN and as an admin for my org. I've included this in the env vars for travis. For some reason travis still never seems to find my package. Any help is greatly appreciated. My NPM version in travis is 3.8.6

Comment: If your repository is open source, can you share a link/URL to a build showing the problem you mention?

Comment: @DominicJodoin it isn't open source unfortunately. Any help is appreciated tho I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you post your .travis.yml file and your build log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by including in my install for travis: `npm set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken $NPM_TOKEN`